# Ruby expression seems to be executing despite "while" modifier being false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my user model:

```
before_save :create_remember_token

  private
    def create_remember_token
      generate_token(:remember_token)
    end

    def generate_token(column)
      begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
    end
```

This works well, but the trouble is that I was expecting it to fail. I was under the impression that the line: `while User.exists?(column=>self[column])` would return **false**, since the record has not yet been saved to the db, and thus, the remember_token would not be set.

But newly created users do have their remember_token set, and I'm a little bit confused as to how this can be possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, is it possible that the code in the loop runs once, before evaluating the conditional? Maybe that's it?

Comment: Change the while to if and try. Does it behave the same way?

Comment: That seems like it might be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering, the code inside a `begin end` expression will run once before the condition is evaluated, unless you provide a rescue clause:

```
# x is not incremented as condition is evaluated first

1.9.3p194 :033 > x=0
 => 0
1.9.3p194 :034 > x+=1 while x>14
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :035 > x
 => 0 

# x is incremented because code inside begin end is evaluated once before the condition 
1.9.3p194 :036 > begin
1.9.3p194 :037 >     x+=1
1.9.3p194 :038?>   end while x>14
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :039 > x
 => 1
```